# Will Ubuntu drivers work on Kubuntu?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kubuntu, displaylink, porting

I need some special drivers for my docking station which are available for Ubuntu. 
Can I also install them on Kubuntu or do I need to port the drivers?

(I want to install these drivers in particular: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)

Comment: yes you can as its the same kernel

Comment: The flavors are the same Ubuntu base, but with a different desktop.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS contains the GNOME desktop, Kubuntu is the same base but with GNOME replaced by KDE (along with GNOME software by KDE software) - drivers are well lower in the software stack (close to the kernel) where both are the same base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The flavors have the same Ubuntu base, but with a different desktop. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS *desktop* provides the GNOME desktop, Kubuntu is the same base but with GNOME replaced by KDE (along with GNOME software being replaced by KDE software).

Drivers (or *kernel modules* in linux talk) are well lower in the software stack (close to the kernel) where both Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Ubuntu-Budgie/Ubuntu-Studio/Ubuntu-Kylin all have the same Ubuntu base.